# Why does this org session src block not give me the right results?

Tags: org-mode, python

I am trying to up my literate coding chops and solving some programming challenges with it.

[Here is the full writeup of the exercise I'm playing with](https://gist.github.com/togakangaroo/74a887984c41e79ea43e5ae263c6324c)

Mostly everything works and I understand everything...except that bit all the way at the bottom.

I have

```
    #+BEGIN_SRC python :session dp-string-gcd :var examples=dp-gcd-examples :results output :exports both 
      def get_string_gcd(shorter, longer):
          if not shorter:
              return None
          if len(shorter) > len(longer):
              return get_string_gcd(longer, shorter)
          current_cycle = []
          for ((s, current_cycle), l) in zip(tracked_cycle(shorter), longer):
              if s != l:
                  return None
          return ''.join(current_cycle)

      for (longer, shorter, desired) in examples:
          desired = desired or None
          gcd = get_string_gcd(shorter, longer)
          print(f'gcd({shorter}, {longer}) = {gcd}')
          if gcd != desired:
              print(f'FAILBOY! it should be {desired}\n')
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : gcd(ABC, ABCABC) = ABC
    : gcd(ABAB, ABABAB) = AB
    : gcd(ABAB, ABABABB) = None
    : gcd(CODE, LEET) = None
```

but that's not really what I want - I would like the function definition to be in a separate src block

The issue is when I do this

```
    #+BEGIN_SRC python :session dp-string-gcd :results none
      def get_string_gcd(shorter, longer):
          if not shorter:
              return None
          if len(shorter) > len(longer):
              return get_string_gcd(longer, shorter)
          current_cycle = []
          for ((s, current_cycle), l) in zip(tracked_cycle(shorter), longer):
              if s != l:
                  return None
          return ''.join(current_cycle)
    #+END_SRC

    #+BEGIN_SRC python :session dp-string-gcd :var examples=dp-gcd-examples :results output :exports both 
      for (longer, shorter, desired) in examples:
          desired = desired or None
          gcd = get_string_gcd(shorter, longer)
          print(f'gcd({shorter}, {longer}) = {gcd}')
          if gcd != desired:
              print(f'FAILBOY! it should be {desired}\n')
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : gcd(ABC, ABCABC) = None
    : FAILBOY! it should be ABC
    : 
    : gcd(ABAB, ABABAB) = None
    : FAILBOY! it should be AB
    : 
    : gcd(ABAB, ABABABB) = None
    : gcd(CODE, LEET) = None
```

I for some reason start getting the function returning `None`! in fact it seems like that happens any time that the first block doesn't have `:results output`. I'm not outputting anything there, I just want the stuff to run in the session.

What is going on that simply changing the results type on the src block can make a python function return something different?